# What is wrong with this Rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, automated-tests

I am new to TDD test driven development and I am trying to do my first few tests and i have this test failing even when i know the title is clearly on the page

```
  response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails | Home")
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong and/or if there is a list of rspec helpers somewhere online. This is a rails 3.2.1 application btw

Update the test is failing with this error

```
Failures:

  1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails | Home")
       expected following output to contain a <title>Ruby on Rails | Home</title> tag:
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.17154 seconds
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:11 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
```

my application.html.haml is

```
!!! Strict
%html{ :xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", 'xml:lang'=>"en", :lang=>"en" }
%head
  %title= "Ruby on Rails | Home"
  = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
  = javascript_include_tag "application"
  = csrf_meta_tags
%body
  = yield



  1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails | Home")
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `page' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x000001011b22e8>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.16401 seconds
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:11 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
```

UPDATE

here is my spec controller with all the tests passing except for the one in question

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do



  describe "GET 'home'" do

    subject { page }

    it "returns http success" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      page.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails | Home")
    end

    it "should render template" do
      get 'home'
      response.should render_template('pages/home')
    end

  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

Yet another update...here is my source when i view source on the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' xml:lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails | Home</title>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/assets/pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="fi3Er/VJrzhpb5FPAcT0DYT9RFNu1oW3p4og5dg+jFc=" name="csrf-token" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Pages#home</h1>

    <p>
      Find me in app/views/pages/home.html
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

yes another update

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'mysql2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.8.0'
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "haml", "~> 3.1.4"
```

Comment: Why is this test failing? what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please show the error. Do you have `webrat` in your Gemfile?

Comment: @nathanvda - updated my question with the failed test

Comment: @KleberS. - updated my question with the failed test

Comment: @Tamer ok, now paste your `views/pages/index.html.erb` contents file, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HAML, your title shouldn't be in between apostrophes. Try:

```
!!! Strict
%html{ :xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", 'xml:lang'=>"en", :lang=>"en" }
%head
  %title Ruby on Rails | Home
  = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
  = javascript_include_tag "application"
  = csrf_meta_tags
%body
  = yield
```

Also, make sure you include `render_views` in your spec file:

```
describe PagesController do
  render_views
.
.
end
```

If that doesn't work. Try using a different gem version of Rspec - there is a bug in RSpec 2.0.0.beta.19

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18'
  gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
end
```

Comment: can you alaborate more...with an example of the right solution for the title tag

Comment: I think he means that your `%title` should be `%title= Ruby on Rails | Home` without the apostrophes. Try that too. I don't know haml so I can't really help you with this.

Comment: you need the apostrophese... uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Home

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you are practicing from the rails tutorial ebook, so, depending of your rspec and ruby version that you have installed, the following should work for you the exactly same way it does for me (I'm actually running the rails tutorial too at this moment!)

Try replacing `content`for `text`like this:

```
response.should have_selector("title", text: "Ruby on Rails | Home")
```

The above line works fine for me.

Also, I have noted you are using `response` where you may probably want to try `page` instead.

the final result will be:

```
page.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails | Home")
```

Hope it helps you.

**EDIT**

Make sure you have declared `page` as `subject` on the first lines from your spec file.

### for example:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do

  subject { page }
  .
  .
end
```

yes another UPDATE...this time my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'mysql2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.8.0'
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "haml", "~> 3.1.4"
```

**EDIT** 
This is the relevant part for `Gemfile`used on the tutorial you are following.

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: Verify the version of `webrat` and `rspec` and make sure you are using the same version used on the tutorial. `Gemfile`is your target.

Comment: no problem. if you are following the rails 3.0 from the tutorial, you can see that the `rspec-rails` version used on the tutorial isn't the same you are.